# CakePHPのfind(‘all’)の多次元配列を検索する方法

Tags: php, cakephp

はじめまして！

itemsテーブルにfavoritesテーブルが関連付けられた状況(Item hasMany Favorite)の以下の配列において、 
Favoriteのuser_idを検索してuser_idに10があるか確認したいのですが、どうすればよいのかわかりません。

このような場合、どのようなコードを記述すればよいでしょうか? 
何かご存知の方は是非ともご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

```
<?php echo $item['Favorite'][0]['user_id']; ?>
```

で12が表示されます。

```
$dataForView = array(
    'items' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Item' => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            ),
            'Purchase' => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            ),
            'Favorite' => array( 
               user_id => 12
            )                                       
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'Item' => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            ),
            'Purchase' => array(
                [maximum depth reached]
            ),
            'Favorite' => array(
                user_id => 23
            )
        ),
           //(int)2~続く
```

Answer (score 1):

Cake2以降なら[Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/core-utility-libraries/hash.html)ユーティリティクラスを使用するのが便利です。

```
$found = Hash::extract($dataForView, 'items.{n}.Favorite[user_id=10]');
```

これで`user_id`が10にマッチするFavoriteが**すべて**抽出されます。
見つからない場合は空の配列が帰りますので、それで判定可能です。